# HTML: Images always getting reloaded from server

Tags: php, html, http, images

I am finding that my web pages' images are always getting loaded from my server, even though they never change. Since these are images, not pages, I can't include an expiration date for them... How can I tell browsers to avoid reloading images they already have?

**Update:**
In PHP I tried using this:

```
  header ("ExpiresByType image/gif \"modification plus 10 minutes\"");
```

but this causes an internal server error.

Answer (score 4):

Your header is incorrect. [Here](http://condor.depaul.edu/dmumaugh/readings/handouts/SE435/HTTP/node24.html) is some documentation. It should be `Expires` as in:

```
 header("Expires: Thu, 30 May 2013 11:26:00 GMT");
```

You generally generate it in PHP like this:

```
 header('Expires: '.date('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + 60*10).' GMT');
```

There is no need to put a type because it is irrelevant. The header simply applies to the result you are serving. You can also use the [max-age header instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8716269/1260172):

```
header('Cache-Control: max-age=600');
```

Answer (score 2):

`ExpiresByType` is an Apache directive, not PHP. Typically you would put this in a `.htaccess` file in the same folder as the images (or in the vhost):

```
ExpiresByType image/gif "modification plus 10 minutes"
```

You will need to have the Apache module `mod_expires` enabled for this to work.

Comment: `"access plus 10 minutes"` would probably be more appropriate, unless maybe these images really are being updated every 10 minutes?